# Conditional SCSS based on ionic platform.height

Tags: css, sass, ionic2

Is there a way to have the scss code respond to the platform height?

In ionic I get the platform height as follows:

```
this.platform.height()
```

I have a class in my app.core.scss file that I would like to have the `max-width` set to 100% if the platform height is >480 and to 50% if the platform height is <=480

Comment: Can you not just use media queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Bill: Try media query first. But what do you mean by platform height ? Is this device screen height?

```
@media screen and (max-height: 480px){
    .CLASS-TO-BE-SET {
        width: 50%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-height: 481px){
    .CLASS-TO-BE-SET {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: @BillNoble: If you are trying to setting for device. there are also some note e.g device orientation portrait and landscape need to be checked as well because device width and height will change based on it. Read more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries